# Внедрение реализаций интерфейсов

Tags: angular2, typescript, angular

Подскажите, правильно ли я понимаю, что Angular не поддерживает внедрение реализаций интерфейсов?

Или это делается как-то иначе?

Например, при попытке написать `providers: {provide:someInterface, useclass:someClass}` идет ругань на интерфейс.

Comment: нужно импортировать этот интерфейс  import {someInterface} from ...

Comment: Делал именно так... А ограничений на дженерики нету?

Comment: под интерфейсом я понимаю объект, который объявлен как interface.

Comment: наконец-то интересный вопрос от вас, на который есть желание дать ответ полноценный =D

Comment: @overthesanity ну в таком случае, жду ответа, как оно правильно делается в Angular. Например, в ASP.NET CORE я мог в одном месте определить, что чего реализует и система сама ресолвила все. Т.е не нужно было имплементацию в каждое место писать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, не поддерживает, потому что интерфейс это сахар, в скомпилированном коде его нету.

Если вы хотите добиться эффекта использования интерфейса с зависимостью - в Angular есть концепция инъекционных токенов (так и называется `InjectionToken`). До Angular 5 концепция называлась `OpaqueToken`.

Перед тем как рассмотрим варианты использования `InjectionToken` - давайте остановимся на `providers` и конструкциях `useClass || useValue || useFactory || useExisting`.

Это множество с префиксом `use` называется `ngInjectableDef` (если дословно перевести - определение инъекции). Любой класс, который вы декорируете с помощью `@Injectable` компилируется в класс со статическим свойством `ngInjectableDef`, выглядит это следующим образом:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private storageService: StorageService) {}
}

// после компиляции

import { defineInjectable, inject } from '@angular/core';

export class AuthService {
  public static ngInjectableDef = defineInjectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
    useFactory: () => new AuthService(inject(StorageService))
  });
}
```

Из этого можно сделать вывод, что в рантайме Angular знает каким образом инстанциировать данный класс, с какими зависимостями и так далее, достаточно вызвать фабрику и закешировать инстанс в инжекторе.

Если вы объявляете класс явно в провайдерах модуля - `providers: [AuthService]`, то это компилируется в:

```
providers: [
  { provide: AuthService, useClass: AuthService }
]
```

Поэтому механизм инъекции `AuthService` в компонент будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
class LoginComponent {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}
}

// рантайм

new LoginComponent(
  resolveDep(loginComponentViewDef, loginComponentElDef, true, AuthService)
);
```

`resolveDep` рекурсивно ищет зависимость в ближайшем инжекторе (в свойствах `providers`), находит, вызывает фабрику и кеширует (либо берет уже инстанс и кеша) и возвращает инстанс.

Возвращаемся к нашим баранам и тому с чего мы начали. `InjectionToken` представляет из себя всего лишь ссылку на что либо. Это может быть фабрика, класс, обычный объект либо какая-то константа.

Как его использовать?

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

interface Config {
  apiUrl: string;
}

const CONFIG = new InjectionToken<Config>('CONFIG', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: () => ({
    apiUrl: 'https://some.api.com'
  })
});
```

В данном случае `CONFIG` - это просто ссылка на объект, который возвращает `factory`. `InjectionToken` принимает первым аргументом строку - описание (`description`), можете туда поместить что угодно, это просто описание токена. Второй аргумент необязательный, используется в случаях если вы не хотите явно указывать токен в провайдерах модуля. Явное указание это:

```
const CONFIG = new InjectionToken<Config>('CONFIG');

providers: [
  {
    provide: CONFIG,
    useValue: { apiUrl: 'https://some.api.com' }
  }
]
```

Фабрику нужно использовать в случаях если нужно произвести какие-то действия перед инициализацией значения, например пользователь использует вашу библиотеку и хочет параметром передать свои сервисы:

```
import { InjectionToken, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';

export const SERVICES = new InjectionToken<any[]>('Reference to the instances');

@NgModule()
export class SomeLibraryModule {
  public static forRoot(services: Type<any>[] = []): ModuleWithProviders<SomeLibraryModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: SomeLibraryModule,
      providers: [
        ...services,
        {
          provide: SERVICES,
          useFactory: (...services: any[]) => services,
          deps: [...services]
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Как получить доступ к зависимости по токену? Для этого используется декоратор `@Inject`:

```
class SomeComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(CONFIG) private config: Config <-- а здесь указываем интерфейс) {}
```

`Inject` не делает ничего сверхъестественного, он просто говорит компилятору Angular, что в данном случае ссылкой на зависимость будет выступать инстанс класса `InjectionToken`. В других случаях вы явно указываете тип зависимости:

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}
```

В данном случае компилятор TypeScript, используя средства библиотеки `reflect-metadata`, сгенерирует необходимую информацию, и опять же компилятор Angular будет знать, что в данном случае ссылкой самой на себя выступает сам класс `AuthService`, то есть конструктор будет ссылаться на инстанс. Если вам интересно как это работает под капотом, вы можете подробней прочитать про рефлексию и DI [тут](https://medium.com/@overthesanity/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-typescript-%D0%B8-angular-ecbbd8e9b938).

Comment: Получается, я могу в одном файле описать словарь InjectionToken, а потом скормить его модулю, а потом импортировать этот файл в каждый модуль, что бы по ключу внедрить нужную конфигурацию?

Comment: это не словарь, это ссылка. Нет, вы создаете файл, в нем создаете токен, провайдите в токен в нужный модуль (либо используете `providedIn`), дальше инжектите этот токен в компоненты/сервисы/куда хотите

Comment: Вы пишите, что второй аргумент нужен, если не хочется явно провайдить в модуль, но и без этого все работает: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6wnldh . Немного не понял: Если я захочу зарегать зависимость на уровне модуля, то всегда нужно использовать useValue или можно как-то можно сослаться на фабрику из InjectionToken? Свойст не нашел.

Comment: оно работает потому что токен не функционирует на уровне DI, а возвращает инстанс сервиса без зависимостей, если бы у этого сервиса были свои зависимости - то токен потребовалось бы объявлять в провайдерах модуля. `то всегда нужно использовать useValue или можно как-то можно сослаться на фабрику из InjectionToken` - нет, вы используете либо `factory`, либо регистрируете токен в модуле и используете любое свойство с префиксом `use`

Comment: Ну т.е, factory, которую я указывают в токене работает, когда дело не доходит до DI? Регистрация на уровне модуля использует совершенно другую фабрику?

Comment: представьте что `HelloService` в конструкторе принимает параметром `HelloStrategy`, а `HelloStrategy` в конструкторе принимает еще 3 зависимости, эти 3 зависимости также имею свои зависимости, я думаю вы себе это не представляете как написать в свойстве `factory` токена, верно?) когда вы объявляете токен в модуле - он становится частью всей системы DI, а также инжектора этого модуля и модуль производит все инициализации за вас

Comment: [про модули можете подробнее прочитать тут](https://medium.com/@overthesanity/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-angular-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8-e9037bb522f0)

Comment: можете привести пример такого сценария: класс, который реализует интерфейс, который в свою очередь в конструкторе зависит от другого интерфейса и первый класс должен заинжектится туда, где он нужен?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ru2rh