# Регистрация провайдера сервиса в соседнем модуле

Tags: angular, angular5

есть такая иерархия модулей

RootModule

- Child_1
- Child_2

я хочу в руте иметь интерфейс `IMyService`

в первом модуле-потомке зарегистрировать его реализацию `MyService`

во втором модуле иметь возможность в компонентах заинжектить `IMyService`, чтобы реализация была та, которая зарегистрирована в первом модуле, но чтобы второй модуль ничего не знал про тип `MyService` в коде.

В c# это реализуется легко, а вот с ангуляром проблемы.

Comment: `@Inject` используй и токены, а вообще это анти-паттерн создавать 1 интерфейс для 1 класса, в TS тебе все равно на что ссылается тип, это не c#. К тому же если ты объявишь сервис в провайдерах 1 модуля, то он не будет доступен в провайдерах другого модуля пока ты не импортируешь этот модуль в другой. Это плохая практика объявлять сервис в провайдерах одного модуля и дальше импортировать этот модуль везде (не считая случаев если ты не делаешь сторонний пакет, например как `@angular/common/http`), в контексте одного приложения достаточно объявлять сервис в корневом инжекторе

Comment: @overthesanity, почему антипаттерн? Паттерны вообще не имеют отношения к конкретной среде. И связывать модули приложения через интерфейсы взаимодействия - это не антиматтерн. На этом принципе создание плагинов основано. Смысл в том, что я хочу вызвать метод какого то абстрактного сервиса, но я ничего не хочу знать про его реализацию и не хочу в коде явно указывать на него ссылки. Использование токенов будет означать эту самую связь, только магическим образом. Неужели в ангуляре нет способа управлять IoC контейнерами?

Comment: твоя проблема в том что ты пытаешься перенести конвенции из c# в TS, давай не будем с тобой спорить на эту тему, но я тебе скажу что сам Хейлсберг (создатель c# и TS) критиковал c# разработчиков которые пытались применить конвенции из c# в TS. Анти-паттерн - потому что интерфейс имеет только 1 реализацию, а это значит, что не должно быть интерфейса вообще. И именовать интерфейсы с префиксом `I` в TS тоже нельзя (это не мое субъективное мнение, так регламентирует майкрософтовский манифест). Смысл в том что IoC в объектно-ориентированном анализе и дизайне это просто инструмент, а реализация

Comment: может быть разная, в твоем случае тебе поможет `@Inject` и токены. Токен в Angular это ссылка, токен может быть self-referenced, например когда ты инжектишь `HttpClient` - это self-referenced токен, то есть класс ссылается сам на себя, и мы получаем его инстанс. А инжектор это просто `lazy hash map`, ключ-значение, всего-то, ключ `HttpClient`, а значение `HttpClientInstance | null`. Ключи можно оверрдайтить со помощью `provide + useValue|useFactory|useClass|useExisting`

Comment: [вот здесь C# разработчик задавал аналогичный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962007/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: @overthesanity реализация может одна только в рамках скоупа. На самом деле их может быть множество. И пытаясь заинжектить интерфейс я хочу сказать: "система, дай мне реализацию, которую считаешь нужной". Но в каком то конкретном случае система может и не знать, какую реализацию использовать, а возложить этот выбор на отдельный модуль. Типа разделение обязанностей. "Модуль, у меня есть некоторое бизнес требование, реализуй мне его, вот тебе интерфейс". При этом система не знает, как он его реализует. Реализация может быть одна, а может меняться за время жизни приложения. Это не конвенция c#.

Comment: @overthesanity, соответственно, токен мне не подходит. Потому что я либо должен буду создавать его в модуле с реализацией и ссылаться из другого модуля на него, либо я должен буду создавать его в корневом модуле, но тогда теряется концепт, потому что я не хочу, чтобы корневой модуль решал, какой будет реализация..

Comment: во-первых я все равно не понимаю зачем тебе все настолько усложнять, я уже сказал, интерфейсы не помогут, это не c#. корневой модуль может решать, в чистой архитектуре это называется "composition root". К тому же в Angular инжекторы объединяются в дерево, и последний инжектор который провайдит зависимость оверрайднет все предыдущие, и если ты затребуешь одну зависимость, то Angular вернет последнюю, а не ту, которая тебе нужна (хотя возможно нужна и последняя). > `должен буду создавать его в модуле с реализацией и ссылаться из другого модуля` - и в чем тут проблема?

Comment: инжекшн интерфейсов идет из c# и джавы, поэтому я и сказал за конвенцию, я не знаю других языков откуда бы шла такая фича. Но ты должен понять что пишешь на JS, где есть прототипы, динамика, нет никаких типов и прочее. Класс и интерфейс должны рассматриваться как взаимозаменяемые при передаче в виде типов, в теории нет причин знать, что ссылка типа, например, `Car` относится к классу, а не к интерфейсу, и наоборот. Я не вижу принципиальной разницы между `constructor(car: Car)` и `constructor(car: ICar)`.

Comment: я даже не знаю какую конкретную задачу решает данный подход, окей, я конкретно указал какую зависимость мне нужно инжекнуть, что при этом ломается? какой-то принцип? :) да ну, теперь я должен изобрести какой-то велосипед, лишь бы поддержать этот принцип, при этом максимально усложнив бизнес логику? архитектор Angular - Мишко, 15 лет писал на джаве и выступал с кучей докладов по "dependency injection", я лучше доверюсь ему и его подходам, чем буду изобретать свой велосипед:) "duplication is far cheaper than the wrong abstraction" @ Sandi Metz

Comment: @overthesanity такой подход решает разделение обязанностей. Интерфейс опишет архитектор, Использует тот, кто будет разрабатывать потребителя и кто-то третий опишет реализацию. То есть после того, как архитектор доделает свои дела, дальше могут приступать разработчики разных модулей. Конечно, архитектор может взять на себя больше, создать все модули, создать сервис с методами без тела и тд, но в этом случае ему потребуется больше времени и разработчики позже приступят к разработке, а это значит, что срок сдачи проекта сдвинется (либо за первый спринт будет готово меньше, чем могло бы быть).

Comment: И еще я не особо представляю как сервис без интерфейса замокать для тестирования. Но это возможно потому, что еще не вникал в принципы модульного тестирования в ангуляре.

Comment: скажу тебе так - я сам когда-то читал книги Мартина, Макконнелла, Фаулера по архитектуре и так далее, вся проблема их книг в том, что у них примеры живут в пространстве языка джава (та же чистая архитектура или идеальный программист Мартина, или совершенный код Стива), и ты сидишь ломаешь голову и думаешь - елки, а как это применить в том же JSe? позже я перестал ломать голову и пришел к тому, что профитнее всего просто следовать официальным манифестам от компаний, который разрабатывают ПО, которое то юзаешь, например манифест от google по написанию кода в angular

Comment: для того, чтобы замокать сервис - тебе нужен сам сервис :)) и интерфейс не поможет, мокание происходит за счет оверрайдинга значения, которое можно получить по ссылке, то есть ссылкой остается сам `CarService`, а вот замоканное значение это например какой-то объект с методами, которые ничего не делают

Comment: в гугл манифесте есть такая концепция, которая называется "core" (ядро), модуль - где ты объявляешь все корневые сервисы, но потом она умерла из-за `providedIn` опции в декораторе. Почему подход с модулями и сервисами плох? У сервисов есть жизненный цикл (у сервиса можно объявлять метод `ngOnDestroy`), если явно провайдить этот сервис в провайдеры компонента (не модуля), то сервис умрет вместе с компонентом, такое не пройдет с модулем, и еще явное указание сервиса всегда легче, потому что в IDE не нужно бегать по кучи файлам и искать реализацию, как говорится "explicit better than implicit"

Comment: @overthesanity, да, наверное, вы правы. Хотя вот по поводу "бегать по куче файлов" могу сказать, что при нормальной архитектуре и тестах этого делать особо и не приходится. Я привык полагаться на интерфейс как на черный ящик. Я знаю, что он должен мне вернуть. Если я заподозрил в нем баг, я сам могу протестировать его в отладке. В любом случае, если вы используете фабричный метод для создания сервиса, у вас будет та же проблема. Поэтому я давно нашел несколько способов отладки черного ящика. А тем более у нас есть исходники этого ящика. :)